# How can I only drop a table and a constraint if they exist?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following script:

```
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestAccount] DROP CONSTRAINT [TestAccount_Application];
        DROP TABLE [dbo].[TestAccount];
```

However the script is failing if the constraint does not exist. What is the best way to check for existance and then only drop the constraint and table if it exists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check existence of a sql server object and drop it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140203/how-to-check-existence-of-a-sql-server-object-and-drop-it)

Answer (score 1):

You're not saying what kind of constraint that is - so I have to guess...

You can use the SQL Server system catalog views to check whether the objects exists before dropping them - something like:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.default_constraint WHERE Name = 'TestAccount_Application')
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestAccount] 
    DROP CONSTRAINT [TestAccount_Application];

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE Name = 'TestAccount')
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[TestAccount];
```

As I said - depending on what kind of constraint that is, you would have to check other system catalog views, like `sys.check_constraints` or `sys.foreign_keys` instead.

You can read more about the system catalog views on [MSDN SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to find constraints just by using count:

```
  select CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, CONSTRAINT_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
  where TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
  order by CONSTRAINT_TYPE asc -- FOREIGN KEY, then PRIMARY KEY
```

Then you could delete the constraints and the table.